# Multiply certain cells in a dataset with a scalar in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pre-process data in Python, and my dataset has some weight values in a column.
Some of the values are in kilograms, like 6400, while others are in a thousand kilograms, like 3.
Is there any way I can multiply the cells in that column with values less than 10 by a certain scalar, say 1000? That way I will be able to make all the cells in the column in kilograms
I'm using pandas to read the csv formatted dataset.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is all pandas here, but why not use a list comparison, if the data maybe needs to processed further - just saying:

```
>>> dataset = [4,9500,9,123000,2000,120]
>>> [ x * 1000 if x < 10 else x for x in dataset ]
[4000, 9500, 9000, 123000, 2000, 120]
```

One thing to mention though, as you might have noticed already, what to do with the values that fall inbetween, such as the number 120. Wouldn't that pose a problem? I guess more info, or thought will be needed here.